# Is there any hint in the Manga that Riko will meet the rest of the white whistles?

Tags: made-in-abyss

Throughout made in abyss we have been presented with white whistles as the most prestigious divers and refereed to as hero's. Currently Riko has been introduced to two of the white whistles, has there been an refferences in the manga or by Akihito Tsukushi if 'Wakuna' and 'srajo' will meet Riko at some point?

Answer (score 1):

To your question specifically, the answer is no.

In the latest chapter (47) and the current arc in general there are many hints regarding to white whistles users. In chapter 47 we learned a very important pice of information that possibly tie to them.

Comment: I would love to add more details on that but since the answer is negative I can't add anything like latest chapter related to this etc. However I can add more I guess.

Comment: @JustPlain Would you be open to revisions? I'm currently posting MiA questions in the hope to bring the tag to life.

Comment: @li x I can't say I understand really well. I think for this I did best I could.